# is there any changes done to the arguments of ghostcript in the new release 9.55.0

Tags: ghostscript, ghostscript.net

we recently upgraded ghostscript from 9.18.0 to 9.55.0. The pdf to tiff conversion is not working with ghostscript version 9.55.0 but it still works with 9.18.0.

We are trying to convert .pdf file to .tiff file using ghostscript. Recently we upgraded the version of ghostscript from 9.18.0 to 9.55.0. below is the arguments we are passing to the version 9.18.0 and it still works fine.tiff file is created

-q -sDEVICE=tiffg4 -r200x200 -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sOutputFile=E:\iCapture\mu\X25470003012022022440.tif E:\iCapture\mu\X25470003012022022440.pdf

But when we are passing same arguments to version 9.55.0 its not cretaing the tiff file. Please let me know if any changes to be done to the arguments or do we need to perform any printer setup action after upgradation of the ghostscript. Because we upgraded the ghostscript software and directly we were trying to convert. are we missing any steps after installation?. Thank you! It will be very helpful if we get any insights on this this issue.

Comment: What do you mean, precisely, by 'not working' ? An error message ? Incorrect output ? Something else ? This is not really the correct forum for this question; if you think you have found a bug then you should open a bug report (http://bugs.ghostscript.com)

Comment: I mean the conversion is not happening and the tiff file is not created.

Comment: And the error message is ? As I said above, if you think you have found a bug you should report it.